# CSV export with different class values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my to_csv function I am wanting to print the name of a particular course, then print under that the name of a module in that course and then each task of that module.
e.g. (multiple headers to allow for easy csv import of same file)

```
Course_name #header
Course1 #course name
Module_name #header
Module1 #module name
Tasks #header
Task1 #task name
Taskdescription #description of task
Taskresult #expected result of task
Task2 #task name
Taskdescription #description of task
Taskresult #expected result of task
Module2 #module name
Tasks #header
Task1 #task name
Taskdescription #description of task
Taskresult #expected result of task
```

In my course model I have:(comments are only in stackoverflow, not in actual code)

```
def to_csv(params)
        CSV.generate do |csv|
            csv << %w{ Course_name }
            csv << [ self.name ]
            csv << %w{ Module_name }
            Mod.all.each do |mod|    #load all mods
                if mod.course_id == self.id do     #match mod to their course and only print those if they match
                    csv << [ mod.name ]
                    Task.all.each do |task|   #load all tasks
                        if task.mod_id == mod.id do     #match task to their module and only print those if they match
                            csv << [ task.name]
                            csv << [ task.description ]
                            csv << [ task.expectedresult ]
                        end
                    end
                end
            end 
    end
```

When I download the CSV file, i only get:

```
Course_name
course1
Module_name
```

so the the program is being caught at `if mod.course_id == self.id do`

not Mod.all.each do |mod| because when I only had that line in it printed every module.

Am I using the right logic check for model or am I missing something else.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks.

***EDIT***:
I tried using

```
Mod.all.each do |mod|
if 1 == 1 do
csv << [ mod.name ]
```

which printed each module name, so the if function works.

Doing:

```
Mod.all.each do |mod|
csv << [ mod.name ]
csv << [ mod.id ]
csv << [ self.id ]
```

results in

```
module1 #mod name
1 #mod id
1 #course id
module2 #mod name
2 #mod id
1 #course id
```

If I use .to_i for both mod.id and self.id that would set both to int 1, for module 1, which should allow the if function to pass. but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `do` from the `if` blocks (it's a valid syntax in Elixir, not in Ruby)

```rb
 if mod.course_id == self.id
```

Comment: This worked marvellously. rather annoying when you have to drop certain keywords in different files. but it works, so yay. thanks.